# Merging dictionaries python without repeating keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge

I'm writing a function where I'm trying to merge together two dictionaries (referred to as databases) without repeating any of the keys or modifying the originals. I think I'm close but I'm currently getting the  error 'db1' is not defined even though it is one of the parameters of the function. Here is an example of two dictionaries and what I need them to look like merged

d1

```
{'Leonardo da Vinci':  [('Mona Lisa', 1503, 76.8, 53.0, 'oil paint', 'France'),
                        ('The Last Supper', 1495, 460.0, 880.0, 'tempera',  'Italy')]}
```

d2

```
{'Pablo Picasso'     : [('Guernica', 1937, 349.0, 776.0, 'oil paint', 'Spain')],
 'Leonardo da Vinci' : [("Portrait  of Isabella d'Este", 1499, 63.0, 46.0, 'chalk', 'France'),
                        ('The Last Supper', 1495, 460.0, 880.0, 'tempera', 'Italy')]}
```

merged

```
{'Pablo Picasso'    : [('Guernica', 1937, 349.0, 776.0, 'oil paint', 'Spain')],
 'Leonardo da Vinci': [('Mona Lisa', 1503, 76.8, 53.0, 'oil paint', 'France'),
                       ("Portrait of Isabella d'Este", 1499, 63.0, 46.0, 'chalk', 'France'),
                       ('The Last Supper', 1495, 460.0, 880.0, 'tempera', 'Italy')]}
```

As you can see the key "Leonardo da Vinci" appears in both dictionaries but should only appear once in the merged dictionary. Thanks to anyone who can help. Here is my current code:

```
def merge_databases (db1,db2):
    ds = [db1, db2]
    d = {}
    for k in db1.iterkeys():
        d[k] = tuple(d[k] for d in ds)
```

Comment: Don't use images.  Paste text so answerers don't have to retype it when trying to help.

Comment: Sure its just more clear with the picture but I'll type it out now

Comment: Just cut-n-paste the original output and code (properly indented). No need to type it out and less chance of error.

Comment: It absolutely isn't clearer. Provide correctly formatted code. Also this problem solves itself, as `'Leonardo da Vinci'` *can* only appear once in the output - dictionary keys must be unique. Also `db1` may be defined as an argument to the function, but **not all of that code is *in* the function**.

Comment: I replaced the image with text and @jon I have included db1 in the function but I guess I may have defined or called it incorrectly

Comment: You've *indented* it incorrectly - whitespace matters in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is what you need:

```
def merge_databases(db1, db2):
    d = {}
    for key in db1.keys() | db2.keys():
        d[key] = db1.get(key, []) + db2.get(key, [])    
    return d
```

or even:

```
def merge_databases(db1, db2):
    return {key: db1.get(key, []) + db2.get(key, []) 
            for key in db1.keys() | db2.keys()}
```

Comment: @n00bprogrammer22 a bit simpler solution